# How to create an environment for libraries and binaries?

Tags: libraries, chroot, dynamic-linking

I have a tool that cannot be run under my Desktop Linux. So I'd like to make a folder that contains all its requirements, and run it in the folder. Virtual machine or container is not a solution here for some reason.

I've bootstrapped an Ubuntu Trusty in `/data/LTS`, and have everything the tool needs installed by running a chroot jail in `/data/LTS`.

Now I issue:

```
PATH=/data/LTS/usr/local/sbin:/data/LTS/usr/local/bin:/data/LTS/usr/sbin:/data/LTS/usr/bin:/data/LTS/sbin:/data/LTS/bin \
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/LTS/usr/local/lib:/data/LTS/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/data/LTS/usr/lib:/data/LTS/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/data/LTS/lib \
PYTHONHOME=/data/LTS/usr \
/data/LTS/usr/bin/python /tmp/test.py
```

I get:

> Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-close.c: 759: _dl_close: Assertion `map->l_init_called' failed!

What should I do?

Comment: It would seem to be an issue with the library `ld.so`. To get more info to go on I'd start w/ `strace -s 2000 -o output.txt <cmd>`, this will show you more about what the command is attempting to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a problem with the loader. I.e you're using the loader from the outside environment.

Try prefixing the command with /data/LTS/lib/ld.so or ld-X.Y.so
This is the loader and by doing it you'll use the one from the enclosed system.

Answer (score 0):

Reason found. It is because of the absolute path to ld.so. Without further modification, /data/LTS/usr/bin/python will use ld.so from actual system instead of fake environment.

`/data/LTS/lib/ld.so /data/LTS/usr/bin/python /tmp/test.py` works.